# change order of x-axis in ggplot2 in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, phyloseq

I have a shiny app created that plots metagenome data using ggplot2, phyloseq, and plotly with dplyr and tidyr. It creates pretty good stacked barplots and heatmaps. The only issue is that it reorders sample names on the x-axis, for example. 1–10 are arranged as 1, 10, 2, 5, 6... How do I correct that bug?

I have tried forcats and reorder but nothing is happening. I believe they are required to be converted to factors, but I'm not sure and i dont know how to do it.

source code is:

```
plot_barplot <- function(
genera,
samples,
cutoff,
modus
){
if (length(samples) == 0){
messagetext <- list(
x = 1,
y = 1,
text = "No sample selected \nplease select a sample"
font = list(size = 28)
)
 plot <- plot_ly(as.data.frame(NULL))
 plot <- plot %>% layout(annotations = messagetext,
                         yaxis = list(visible = FALSE),
                         xaxis = list(visible = FALSE))
 } else {
 plotdata <- dplyr::select(genera$Abundance, all_of(samples))
  if (ncol(plotdata) > 1) {
  plotdata$Total <- rowSums(plotdata)
  circ = F
 } else if (ncol(plotdata) == 1) {
  plotdata$copy <- plotdata[1]
  plotdata$Total <- rowSums(plotdata) / 2
  circ = T
 }
 plotdata <- plotdata[order(plotdata$Total,
                           decreasing = T),]
 plotdata <- rbind(plotdata[1:cutoff,],
                  colSums(plotdata[(cutoff + 1):nrow(plotdata),]))
 row.names(plotdata)[nrow(plotdata)] <- "#others"
 if (circ == T | modus == "total"){
  plotdata <- dplyr::select(plotdata, Total)
  plotdata$Name <- row.names(plotdata)
  plot <- plotly::plot_ly(plotdata,
                          labels = ~Name,
                          values = ~Total,
                          type = "pie")
 } else {
  plotdata <- dplyr::select(plotdata, -Total)
  if (modus == "hide_others"){
    plotdata <- dplyr::slice_head(plotdata, 
    n = (nrow(plotdata)    -1))  
  }
  datapoints <- colnames(plotdata)
  plotdata$Name <- row.names(plotdata)
  plotdata <- tidyr::pivot_longer(plotdata,
                                  datapoints,
                                  names_to = "Sample",
                                  values_to = "Abundance")
  if (modus %in% c("absolute", "hide_others")){
    plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(plotdata,
                            ggplot2::aes(fill = Name,
                                         y = Abundance,
                                         x = sample))
    plot <- plot + ggplot2::geom_bar(position = "stack",
                                     stat = "identity")
    plot <- plot + ggplot2::theme_classic()
    plot <- plotly::ggplotly(plot)
  } else {
    plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(plotdata,
                            ggplot2::aes(fill = Name,
                                         y = Abundance,
                                         x = Sample))
    plot <- plot + ggplot2::geom_bar(position = "fill",
                                     stat = "identity")
    plot <- plot + ggplot2::theme_classic()
    plot <- plotly::ggplotly(plot)
    }
   }
  }


    return(plot)
   }
```

Comment: Pass the data as integer not as character. For any further help please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: check the code please

Comment: That is just a function not a full reproducible example. Please see [this](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).

Comment: can you tell where to add the modifications for conversion of data as integer, as i am very new at all of these.

Comment: try `x = as.integer(sample)`

Comment: it showed this error Error:cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'integer'